# Onepage scroller panels not 100% height

Tags: jquery, css

I have a 1 page scrolling plugin on my site that I'm testing out, I have it working but the panels are not 100% height, I have copied the CSS from the demo but still not working correctly so I'm wondering if I'm doing something basic wrong. You can see my issue [here](http://foley13.webfactional.com/test/#1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every parent element of .onepage-wrapper must have height:100% in order to make it full height.

You can add the following CSS to your page:

```
.site,
.site-inner,
.site-content,
.content-area,
.site-main {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use absolute positioning for each panel - let the default CSS layout rules work for you. Remove all `position: absolute`s and their position properties for all panels, and all will be well.

Comment: Removing position absolute didnt work to well, that positioning was in the javascript and changing it didnt work but thankyou.